# Rewrite url with query string in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rule

Today I try to rewrite some ugly url in order to be cache by browser! But the problem is that I have multiparameters inside the url. An example is better than a long text :

the actual url with the ? and the & :

```
http://images.mydomain.com/lib/simple-thumb.php?src=http://google.com&l=180&h=135&zc=1
```

And I want to use this instead :

```
http://images.mydomain.com/lib/http://google.com/180/135/1
```

Should I use the rule below in my .htaccess?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{query_string} ^(.*)$
rewriterule simple-thumb\.php /lib/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

But not seams to be work...

Thanks for your kind help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/lib/http\:\/\/google.com/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /lib/simple-thumb.php?src=http://google.com&l=$1&h=$2&zc=$3
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I try but not working. How do you manage and assign the parameters like this &l= inside the $1?

Comment: I am sorry a typo. try again in a sec.

Comment: Try now mate....and the brackets capture the numbers and they are numbered sequentially so the first bracket is $1 and the second is $2 and so on